# SIngle character y and Y get dumped as YAML 1.1 booleans

Tags: python, boolean, ruamel.yaml

When I do:

```
from ruamel import yaml

seq = ["x", "y", "z", "Y", "true", True]
print(yaml.dump(seq, version=(1,1)))
```

it gives:

```
%YAML 1.1
--- [x, y, z, Y, 'true', true]
```

but I expected the `y` and `Y` to be quoted, because these get loaded back as booleans because this is YAML 1.1. 
Moreover [this
bug](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/285/#30f7), indicates this problem is
solved.

Why is this bug marked as closed, when it still shows this error even on version ruamel.yaml>=0.15.93?

Comment: This issue was posted as a response to user [Ark-kun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497385/ark-kun) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44211899/special-significance-to-single-n-character-in-yaml/44213322?noredirect=1#comment108344723_44213322)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the unsafe PyYAML compatibility function `dump()` (and besides you do so in an inefficient way). That function is outdated but emulates PyYAML's erroneous behaviour.

You
should instead
instantiating a `YAML()` instance and using its `.dump()` method.

```
import sys
import yaml as pyyaml
import ruamel.yaml

seq = ["x", "y", "z", "Y", "true", True]
print("PyYAML version:", pyyaml.__version__)
pyyaml.dump(seq, sys.stdout, default_flow_style=None, explicit_start=True, version=(1,1))
print()

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.version = (1,1)
yaml.default_flow_style=None
print("ruamel.yaml version:", ruamel.yaml.__version__)
yaml.dump(seq, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
PyYAML version: 5.3.1
%YAML 1.1
--- [x, y, z, Y, 'true', true]

ruamel.yaml version: 0.16.10
%YAML 1.1
--- [x, 'y', z, 'Y', 'true', true]
```

Comment: Thank you for the writeup and the example. >"You should instead instantiating a YAML() instance and using its .dump() method.". I tried that too (I used the code from the original bug), but got different results. The problem was that setting the version did not always work correctly until v0.16.3. When I tried "yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(); yaml.dump(val, sys.stdout); yaml.version = (1,1); yaml.dump(val, sys.stdout)". In v<=0.16.2 the second dump has the "%YAML 1.1" directive, but no quoting.

Comment: P.S. From a user perspective I find it really confusing that `ruamel.yaml.dump(val, sys.stdout, version=(1,1))` behaves differently from your example..

Comment: I understand that it is confusing, but the history of ruamel.yaml is that it started out to be compatible with PyYAML, fixing bugs and a adding backwards compatible features (after merging its two code bases for PY2 and PY3), but at some point that was holding back real (non-backwards compatbile) improvements and I had to switch to the new API (but left the old in).