# How can I dump YAML 1.1 booleans (y, n, T, F, etc) as quoted strings with ruamel.yaml

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

Already read https://stackoverflow.com/a/61252180/1676006 and it doesn't seem to have solved my problem.

Using ruamel.yaml:

```
    yaml = YAML(typ="safe")
    yaml.version = (1, 1)
    yaml.default_flow_style = None
    yaml.dump(stuff, sys.stdout)
```

With a python dict `stuff` containing:

```
{
    "key": "Y"
}
```

outputs

```
%YAML 1.1
--- {key: Y}
```

in the output yaml. In my actual code, I'm piping this into helm, which is backward compatible with yaml 1.1, meaning that I need to have anything that might be a boolean scalar quoted. What am I missing here?

E: because I am a big dummy and forgot to update everything after trying a min repro - here's the REPL output:

```
>>> from ruamel.yaml import YAML
>>> yaml = YAML()
>>> yaml.version = (1,1)
>>> yaml.default_flow_style = None
>>> stuff = {
...     "key": "T"
... }
>>> import sys
>>> yaml.dump(stuff, sys.stdout)
%YAML 1.1
--- {key: T}
>>>
```

E again: I am shamed. T isn't a scalar boolean, I was using the wrong test subject. This is not a place of honour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Python dict really consists of a single key value pair, mapping of a string to a string, **as you indicate**,  `ruamel.yaml`  will not dump the output you display
with or without `typ='safe'`)

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = {
  "key": "Y"
}
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.version = (1, 1)
yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1, 1)
yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
%YAML 1.1
--- {key: 'Y'}
%YAML 1.1
--- {key: 'Y'}
```

Not even changing the value to a boolean gets your result

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

data = dict(key=True)
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
yaml.version = (1, 1)
yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.version = (1, 1)
yaml.default_flow_style = None
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
%YAML 1.1
--- {key: true}
%YAML 1.1
--- {key: true}
```

Always, always, **always** provide a minimal program that can be cut-and-pasted to get the results that you are seeing.
That is how I produce my answers ( the answers are actually comming from a multidocument YAML file processed by (`ryd`)[https://pypi.org/project/ryd/)), and that is how you should consider providing your questions.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to let you know to check my edits - I am, in fact, a big dummy and had crossed a bunch of wires in my testing. Apologies for the bad q!